# AngularJS don't see script

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hapi.js

I'm using AngularJS + Hapi.js
Trying to create a simple ng-view example, but AngularJS don't see my custom script. Simple using src for app.js gave me an error in Chrome console. I tried to use ng-src, but nothing happens.

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script ng-src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script ng-src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script ng-src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script ng-src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.7/angular-material.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="testApp">
    <div ng-view></div>

    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### app.js

```
'use strict'

var app = angular.module('testApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider'], function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    });
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.message = "Hello!";
}])
```

### main.html

```
<h1>
    {{ message }}
</h1>
```

### server.js

```
'use strict';

const Hapi = require('hapi');
const Hoek = require('hoek');
const Handlebars = require('handlebars');

const server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ port: 3000 });

server.register(require('vision'), (err) => {
    Hoek.assert(!err, err);

    server.views({
        engines: {
            html: Handlebars
        },
        path: __dirname,
        layout: 'index'
    });

    server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    handler: {
        view: 'index'
    }
});
});

server.start((err) => {

    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log(`Server running at: 3000`);
});
```

App structure:

```
server.js
index.html
 - app
   app.js
   main.html
```

Comment: what error is thrown on console?

Comment: "http://localhost:3000/app/app.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Comment: This is something related to HapiJS. Use `inert` (http://hapijs.com/tutorials/serving-files) package to serve files rather serving `index.html` only. In your server code you have exposed HTML file only; nothing else, that's why for app.js it fails.

Comment: So angular and plugins are in existence because of initial 4 `script[src]`. But later `app.js` script tag couldnt get the app.js file and hence your app didn't work.

Comment: in head tag you did't give 'angular-route.js' file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few bits that need fixing.

First to get hapi to server the app files install inert.

```
npm install inert --save
```

Add then register the route to server.js the files under /app. This route should be registered first.

```
server.register(require('inert'), (err) => {
    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/app/{param*}',
        handler: {
            directory: {
                path: './app',
                redirectToSlash: true,
                index: true
            }
        }
    });
});

server.register(require('vision'), (err) => {
    Hoek.assert(!err, err);

    server.views({
        engines: {
            html: Handlebars
        },
        path: __dirname,
        layout: 'index'
    });

    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/',
        handler: {
            view: 'index'
        }
    });
});
```

Remove the ng-src directives from the angular scripts in index,html and add angular-route as well.

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.7/angular-material.min.js"></script>
```

In your app.js fix the templateUrl remove the ] in the controller.

```
'use strict'

var app = angular.module('testApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider'], function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'app/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    });
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.message = "Hello!";
})
```

Comment: It looks great and must work great, but now in console error:
"Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=testApp&p1=Error%3…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.15%2Fangular.min.js%3A34%3A399)" in agnular.js

Tried to set scripts local and with bower – all same.

Comment: @mummakill That looks like the error that the ngRoute script is missing. Did you add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js"></script>` as well?

Comment: Yes :) Problem was resolved in app.js:

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'app/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    });
}]);

by transfering square bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Your app.js file should be like this:

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    });
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.message = "Hello!";
})
```

In controller, you had closed the controller with square brackets; removed.
In app config, the dependencies; if passed in array then function will be the last item of array; config should close by array closing i.e. square bracket.

Comment: this I have explained in the comments to question. It is related to hapi configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a problem with the relational src in your script tag. Try changing it to the following absolute path:

```
<script src="/app/app.js"></script>
```

Assuming the app folder is in the root of your website.